# how to locate the point of OutOfMemoryError exception on uiautomator test cast

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-uiautomator

i've got an OOM exception on my uiautomator project but the error stacks doesn't mention any of my code,how to find out the error point? here is the logs:

```
143|root@aries:/ # uiautomator runtest /sdcard/test.jar -c com.simple.test
.test1
mator runtest /sdcard/test.jar -c com.simple.test.test1             <
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
com.simple.test.test1:
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testStart
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=com.simple.test.test1
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=.Test run aborted due to unexpected except
ion: Failed to allocate a 15748050 byte allocation with 10501096 free bytes and
10MB until OOM
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 15748050 byte allocation with 1
0501096 free bytes and 10MB until OOM
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.j
ava:95)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:12
5)
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:278)
        at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:123)
        at java.io.PrintWriter.doWrite(PrintWriter.java:623)
        at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:601)
        at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:579)
        at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:641)
        at java.io.PrintWriter.print(PrintWriter.java:453)
        at java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:549)
        at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.getFilteredTrace(BaseTestRunner.java:306)

        at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.getFilteredTrace(BaseTestRunner.java:277)

        at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner$WatcherResul
tPrinter.addError(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:319)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.addError(TestResult.java:43)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
        at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.start(UiAuto
matorTestRunner.java:160)
        at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.run(UiAutoma
torTestRunner.java:96)
        at com.android.commands.uiautomator.RunTestCommand.run(RunTestCommand.ja
va:91)
        at com.android.commands.uiautomator.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:83)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:251)

Time: 24.346

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 0,  Errors: 1
```

or how can i debug uiautomator projects with breakpoints step by step?thanks.

Comment: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 15748050 byte allocation with 10501096 free bytes and 10MB until OOM` It seems you're trying to load a huge text file all into memory at once.

Comment: As noted obliquely in the Mayuso answer below, your app appears to be allocating a large amount of memory for a StringBuilder.  Look for StringBuilder.append calls in a loop or string concatenation (which java optimizes to use StringBuilder).

Comment: thanks,ya i know what the error stacks told,but there is a lot of code on my project and the point is it didn't mention any of my code in this error stacks,all the methods mentioned above are belongs to the uiautomator itself.i don't know what's wrong with my code.thanks again.

Comment: what i thinking is,considering the junit.framework.TestResult.addError,is the error might  occured on while it trying to tell an error contain a large message?